# RXJS perform a request and then iterate over the result with more requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the proper way of executing the following scenario with RxJS:

1. Perform an HTTP request.
2. Wait for the response and iterate over a list returned to perform a follow-up request for each item in the list - in parallel.

From what I have read for first I should use concatMap and for the second step mergeMap?
Can you help with the syntax?

```
this.httpService.get(itemListUrl).pipe(
  // first request
  concatMap(itemListUrl => {
    this.logger.debug(timestamp() + ': Sending request to ' + itemListUrl);
    // perform follow-up (parallel) https requests for every entry in the list returned.
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator (or [other higher-order RxJS mapping operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)) in combination with the RxJS [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) function to send requests for each of the result items.

Try the following approach:

```js
this.httpService
  .get(itemListUrl)
  .pipe(switchMap((res) => forkJoin(...res)))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    // Process the full result here..
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Amer, I believe your answer is correct. However, in my case the first response contains a list of thousands of follow-on HTTP requests and I couldn't find a way to put a limit on the parallel requests I can apply with switch map and my server crashed, that is why I wanted to use mergeMap. I ended up executing individual HTTP requests in a for loop though :)